# How to filter object in array and return only number ? Javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi my array is right now like this:

```
let array = [
{dokument_id: 1, location_id: 19, item: 1, num: 1},
{dokument_id: 3, location_id: {id: 24, naziv: "Test 2"}, item: 2, num: 2},
{dokument_id: 2, location_id: {id: 26, naziv: "Test 3"}, item: 3, num: 3}
]
```

I need to loop thought array and return same array but without location_id as object then only location_id :1 or location_id 2

example filtered array:

```
{dokument_id: 1, location_id: 19, item: 1, num: 1},
{dokument_id: 3, location_id: 24, item: 2, num: 2}, // no more location_id : object
{dokument_id: 2, location_id: 26, item: 3, num: 3} // no more location_id : object
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get either the nested property or the value from the not nested property for mapping new objects.

If the nested property is not given, the second expression is evaluated. it works together with a [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR).

The new object contains the spreaded object ([spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)) and adds/replaces a new property.

```js
let array = [{ dokument_id: 1, location_id: 19, item: 1, num: 1 }, { dokument_id: 3, location_id: {id: 24, naziv: "Test 2"}, item: 2, num: 2 }, { dokument_id: 2, location_id: {id: 26, naziv: "Test 3"}, item: 3, num: 3 }],
    result = array.map(o => ({ ...o, location_id: o.location_id.id || o.location_id }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -1):

this will loop through the `array` and produce the desired result.

> For every element `ele` in `array`, it will put the `location_id` to `location_id.id`

```
array.forEach(function(ele) {
  if (ele.location_id.id) {
    ele.location_id = ele.location_id.id;
  }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check the below answer. It will update location id in an array of objects.

```js
array.forEach((x) => {
    if (typeof(x.location_id) === 'object') {
        x.location_id = x.location_id.id
    }
});
```